# How to extract json data from the response - Java

Tags: java, json, response

I am trying to extract data from Json string which is obtained by a response using only Java code.
I am posting my Java code here.

OUTPUT:

```
Entering into while loop
[{"name":"Frank","food":"pizza","quantity":3}]
```

This is my Java code.

```
public void receive() 
{    
System.out.println("Entering into sendNote method");   
try {
// make json string,
String json = "{\"name\":\"Frank\",\"food\":\"pizza\",\"quantity\":3}";
// send as http get request
URL url1 = new URL("http://myurl/file.php?usersJSON="+userList);
URLConnection conn1= url1.openConnection();
//I am receiving exactly what I have sent....
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn1.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
{
System.out.println("Entering into while loop");
System.out.println(line);// line contains the received json parameters
//I want to enter the recieved parameters into my database
//
//
//
//I need the solution right here....
}
rd.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
System.out.println("Error Occured while receiving");
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Thank you !!!!!

@Ankur:
This is how I tried,

[image: This is one of your second ways... I called the function from where I wanted and passed the variable "line" containing the json string]

@ Lahiru Prasanna, @ankur-singhal 
Thanks a lot.!!

Comment: Why don't you use Google Gson API? (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: use 3rd party JSON api called GSON for your req. Also you can use JSONbject support provided by java itself

Comment: Checking..., but if I get exact implementation of the code, that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you successfully got HttpResponse.here variable called response is HttpResponse.

```
        // Could do something better with response.
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        StringBuilder   builder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                content.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
            JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error:  " + e.toString());
        System.out.println( "" + e.toString());
        System.out.println("" + e.toString());
    }
```

And important thing is never use Strings for json operations.

you can retrieve your data from jsonObject like this

```
String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
```

Comment: Showing error at StatusLine, HttpEntity ,builder.toString() and JSONException. And there's nothing to import

Comment: are using eclipe or netbeans? click on that bulb icon

Comment: Netbeans... Bubble button is not showing import option.

Comment: import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

add these lines

Comment: oh sorry you have to import external library

Comment: download this http://mirror.metrocast.net/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.3.5-bin.zip

Comment: i think that libraries are correct.i am using that code in my android app.android sdk defaultly provide em.

Comment: It's not working. Even I have android code version but that isn't working.

Comment: where is the error?can you send me your code to this mail

prasanna@ceylonlinux.lk

Comment: I think I have some issues with the libraries. I am getting lots of errors. I'll try to make it right .. anyway thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways to achive the same.

1.) Create a `response pojo`

```
MyResponse ob = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, MyResponse.class);
```

// then call getters on above.

2.) Get `key/values`

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(""name":"Frank","food":"pizza","quantity":3}");
System.out.println("name=" + json.get("name"));
System.out.println("width=" + json.get("food"));
```

3.) Converting `Json` to `HashMap`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        jsonToMap("{\"name\":\"Frank\",\"food\":\"pizza\",\"quantity\":3}");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void jsonToMap(String t) throws JSONException {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(t);
    Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        String value = jObject.getString(key);
        map.put(key, value);

    }

    System.out.println("json : " + jObject);
    System.out.println("map : " + map);
}
```

**output**

```
json : {"name":"Frank","food":"pizza","quantity":3}
map : {food=pizza, name=Frank, quantity=3}
```

Comment: I tried to put that code , but it seems to be not working.. I couldn't resolve some errors too.

Comment: @Kaage all 3 should work, what are the errors you are getting.

Comment: Where am i supposed to put MyResponse ob = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, MyResponse.class); ???   and  Where to call jsonToMap function ?? I am bit confused, sorry .

Comment: @Kaage First of all i have given you `3 different approaches`, you have `json string` with you, and you can pass it in any of the approaches.

Comment: ok,, I tried using 2nd way. but I got this error when I run the file "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject"

Comment: @Kaage answer edited with the output, now try. I think you were putting square brackets `[` and `]`, these are actually for array or collections

Comment: I couldn't implement the exact code but I could surely use the idea.... Thank you.!