# how to get particular data in json response

Tags: java

I have fetched data using Http request and the output was json response by passing api.

output:

```
`[{"id":23908,"attributes":{"batteryLevel":69.0,"distance":0.29,"totalDistance":74804.18,"motion":false},
"deviceId":5,"type":null,"protocol":"osmand",
"serverTime":"2018-04-18T12:08:02.814+0000",
"deviceTime":"2018-04-18T12:08:06.000+0000",
"fixTime":"2018-04-18T12:08:06.000+0000",
"outdated":false,
"valid":true,"latitude":12.79057744,"longitude":77.85007493,"altitude":771.0,
"speed":0.0,"course":0.0,"address":null,"accuracy":0.0,"network":null}]`
```

now I need only particular data as json response eg:only lattitude as json response how can i achieve it.

Comment: please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291995/how-to-extract-json-data-from-the-response-java

Comment: what did you try? can you show us your code?